# How to debug JavaScript in JSP using Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, xdebug

Is there anyway to debug and step through JavaScript inside a JSP page using Eclipse? I am on the Oxygen version of Eclipse.

I tried installing the Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web developers because it sounded like it might allow debugging but that version of the IDE doesn't recognize JSPs.  I also tried searching the marketplace to see if I could find a plugin to do this as well with no luck.

I realize I could just use browser developer tools but it would be easier if all of it could be done from Eclipse.

Comment: Could you not use a Script tag and move your JavaScript to a js file and debug that?

Comment: The browser never sees the original JSP contents, so this is unlikely to ever work the way you want. You can try installing the Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools from the Oxygen update site; it contains the JSP Editor. If you need to create a Dynamic Web Project, you'll need the Java EE Developer Tools. Both of these would have added the same Javascript and HTML tools that you already have.